# Printing records from a VSAM KSDS shows characters with periods

Tags: mainframe, zos, jcl, vsam

I am trying to view the contents of a VSAM dataset using the following jcl code:

```
//REPRO2   JOB  REPROJCL
//IDCAMS   EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT DD   SYSOUT=A
//SYSIN    DD   *,SYMBOLS=EXECSYS
      PRINT -
            INDATASET(ZXP.TEST.GAS.PRODPROC) -
            CHAR
/*
```

However the data has periods for example:

```
0KEY OF RECORD - 94...-...6-594
 94...-...6-594*Y..1ZS0.UGV...==
0KEY OF RECORD - 94...-...4-521
 94...-...4-521*Y...Y2..LVJ1Y...
0KEY OF RECORD - 97...-...0-101
```

How can I view the data without periods, does printing in hex then converting to ascii/ebcdic work?

Comment: The period represent `binary bytes` i.e. have values. You need the *Record Layout* and convert them to text

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation, here:  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zvse/6.2?topic=SSB27H_6.2.0/fe6cm_idcams_commands_print.html ?  As @BruceMartin say, it explains what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the DUMP option on the PRINT statement instead of CHAR.  That will print the records in hexadecimal dump format so you can see the binary values.